# Why is Flexigird not working on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexigrid

I have a page with a flexigrid on it and it works on FF,Chrome,Opera except IE.
it points out that the error is at line of "if(!btn.separator)" which is null or not an object.

Well, every thing inside that block is an error on IE cause i think the error is on the "btn" objects..

has anyone ever encountered this error?

```
this is from the latest version of flexigrid
```

for(i=0;i< p.buttons.length;i++){
var btnfor  = p.buttons[i];
if(!btn.separator)
{
//do things here
}
}

Thanks
Jrubins

Comment: i have two pages with flexigird.. The 1 without custom buttons is working. and the one that has buttons in it is not working.

Comment: we need to see some code to debug the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for a reply. but i was just able to fix my problem.

by using `for (i in p.buttons)` instead of `for(i=0;i< p.buttons.length;i++)`

probably it was the index "i" data type as object and not int?.